# angular-sidebarjs - sidebar not closing on button click in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am new in angular and I have been using angular-sidebarjs in my app. I have given my code of sidebar directive below.

in my template:

```
<sidebarjs>
  <div class="sidebar-head">Find User</div> 
  <nav>
    <ul class="sidebar-menu">
      <li ng-repeat="radius in radius">
         <a href="#" ng-click="listMenus()" ui-sref="users({radius_id: radius_id})" ui-sref-opts="{reload: true}">radius.name</a>
      </li>
     </ul>
   </nav>
 </sidebarjs>
```

in my home.js:

```
var home = angular.module('wm.home',[uiRouter,'ngSidebarJS'])
```

When I click on an option among the list, sidebar doesn't close and the required page loads behind. sidebar closes only when I click on the toggle button or outside the sidebar.

How to close the sidebar onclick of any of the options in the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the attribute `sidebarjs-toggle` to your options, like this:

```
<sidebarjs>
  <div class="sidebar-head">Find User</div> 
  <nav>
    <ul class="sidebar-menu">
      <li ng-repeat="radius in radius">
         <a sidebarjs-toggle href="#" ng-click="listMenus()" ui-sref="users({radius_id: radius_id})" ui-sref-opts="{reload: true}">radius.name</a>
      </li>
     </ul>
   </nav>
 </sidebarjs>
```

Also, I think you should remove that `href="#"` because you are already doing the routing with the `ui-sref`.